# How to replace mortar above lintel

Tags: windows, mortar

We have a brick house and our windows have an iron lintel above them, with a layer of mortar on top of the lintel and bricks on top of the mortar.  For one window, it looks like water got under the mortar and caused the iron to rust.  I removed the mortar/rust, but don't know what to do from here.  The current gap is about 3/4" (fat finger width.  Should I just fill with type N mortar and call it good, or should the plate be replaced as well?  As far as I can tell the plate looks to be in good shape.

As suggested in the comments, this may not be DIY friendly.  Any help in understanding potential issues is appreciated.

We are getting new windows installed soon and this area is supposed to be wrapped in vinyl so I hope this won't be a problem again.

[image]

Comment: The rusted metal is the lintel (beam) that holds the weight of brick above the window opening. Though rusty, it may or may not require replacement. I don't think it is safe to DIY. Hire a mason to check it out and do it the proper way. Even only requires sealing.

Comment: @r13 Does the lintel always bear the weight of the brick?  The contractor putting in the windows said it does not support the bricks (may not have known what he is talking about).

Comment: Yes. Unless you have a brick arch over the window, the lintel is there to support the weight of the brick. Otherwise, cracks in the brick will soon occur, noticeably diagonally from the corner of the windows, and the middle.

Comment: @r13 I don't understand why this is not DIY friendly.  To me, it seems like I should just slap some mortar in there and call it good.  If you post an answer helping me understand the potential issues then I'll gladly accept it.  Not trying to argue the point, I just want to understand.  Thanks

Comment: I mistook the lintel that has rusted away. I apologize for my mistake. But look at the photo again, it is clear the bricks above have started to loosen, evident by the widened mortar seam above the 2nd bricklayer.  You can use the dry pack to seal the gap by yourself, but sooner or later you'll have to deal with the brick. So, I think this matter should be handled by an experienced mason from the begining.